# avoid of changing roles on user profile edit in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my project I have roles and permissions and also I made a controller for my users so they can edit their profile because usercontroller is limited to admin roles only.

Now my problem is, when user update his profile his role access will be detach.
What should I do to user be able to edit his own profile without changing his role?

this is my update function:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $user = User::findOrFail($id); //Get role specified by id

  //Validate name, email and password fields
      $this->validate($request, [
          'name'=>'required|max:120',
          'username'=>'required|max:120',
          'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
          'password' => 'nullable|string|min:6|confirmed'
      ]);
      $input = $request->only(['name', 'username', 'email']); //Retreive the name, email and password fields
      if (trim(Input::get('password')) != '') {
        $user->password = Hash::make(trim(Input::get('password')));
      }

      $user->fill($input)->save();
      return view('users.profile')
          ->with('flash_message',
           'Your Profile successfully edited.');
    }
```

User Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'password',  'affiliate_id', 'referred_by',
    ];
```

Database:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('referred_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('affiliate_id')->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `when user update his profile his role access will be detach`?

Comment: How is the role attached to the User? Is it a property on the User model? A join table?

Comment: @tompec it means when my users edit their info like their username when they save it they will lose their roles their role column in their database become empty

Comment: @Cryode I updated my question I use middleware and tables in db one for roles one for permissions.

Comment: Can you retrieve their existing user-value from the session _or_ db, add it to $input and then re-save it? It's the $user objeect that you're calling `fill` on, why not operate directly on the user-object, or use something besides `fill`

Comment: Fill is just populating the object. https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill If you know the user-role id, then get it, add it to the array that `fill` is using & save it. `sync` is a super-useful one for persisting cross-table changes.

Comment: You mention a role column, however there isn't one in your code samples. It's very difficult to help without seeing anything relating to roles, and how a user is given a role.

Comment: @Cryode Currently roles are given by admins (manually) I also wanted to make it by default when user is registered getting role eg. user role. any idea how I fix this issue? what pages codes you need i publish?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the role of the user in the edit view that if it is admin you will show the role checkboxes or whatever you have used and if not admin you will not show roles.

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{   
    $user_role = User::findOrFail($id)->roles->toArray();
    return view('UserCRUD.edit')->with('user_role', $user_role);
}
```

And in view

```
@if($user_role == 'admin')
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="value">
    </label>
@endif
```

If you show roles then only they will be in the `$request->all()` array
If I `dd($request->all())` while not showing roles in view

```
array:8 [▼
    "_method" => "PATCH"
    "_token" => "8xxRjgKaJNlJOwZZ2vZYecs6GrEWjpYqbCtWULJO"
    "username" => "testcase1"
    "email" => "test1@test.com"
    "password" => ""
    "confirm_password" => ""
    "firstname" => "Test"
    "lastname" => "One"
]
```

And if I `dd($request->all())` while showing roles in view

```
array:9 [▼
    "_method" => "PATCH"
    "_token" => "8xxRjgKaJNlJOwZZ2vZYecs6GrEWjpYqbCtWULJO"
    "username" => "testcase1"
    "email" => "test1@test.com"
    "password" => ""
    "confirm_password" => ""
    "firstname" => "Test"
    "lastname" => "One"
    "role" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "2"
    ]
]
```

And when updating you just need to check that if roles are set you update them else not.

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->update($request->all());
if (isset($request->all()['role'])) {
    $user->roles()->sync($request->all()['role']);
}
```